# Android spinner scroll to the top

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I have spinner with items created in `getDropDownView()` method. After the spinner is created I don't know why it scrolls to the last item in spinner (spinner is larger than whole screen view). 
What I have now what scrolls to the bottom:

```
        spinner.adapter = adapter
        spinner.setSelection(adapter.count)
        spinner.prompt = "my hint"
```

`spinner.setSelection(-1)` does not satisfy me cause it makes 1st item selected - then hint is invisible.

Question is how to scroll to the top of spinner items without selecting item? ScrollY, ScrollTo does not work here.

Greetings

Comment: Or maybe I can ```setSelection(-1)``` and then somehow unselect it and mark it as unselected?

Comment: Just remove `setSelection(int position)` method from your code.

Comment: This does not solve the problem still item at position 0 is selected

Comment: can you add your Spinner xml?

Comment: do you used AppCompatSpinner ?

Comment: I created my own spinner which extends from Spinner and xml marked it as dropdown. Nothing fancy just changed dimens. Created it to show part of spinner (in default it takes as much space as he has items)

Comment: @CallMePedro did my answer solve issue?

Comment: @buzzingsilently unfortunately  no :(

Comment: Please share more detailed case study.

Answer (score 2):

From the question above I understand that you want to show hint when nothing is selected from spinner list.

Add hint at position zero of your list, i.e.

```
list.add("my hint");
list.add("option 1");
list.add("option 2");
.
.
list.add("option n");
```

And when user selects item from spinner list check that hint is not selected, i.e.

```
if (selectedPosition != 0)
    Toast.makeToast(context, list.get(selectedPosition), Toast.TOAST_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can I know why you are using `spinner.setSelection(adapter.count)` ?

Just remove -> `spinner.setSelection(adapter.count)`
or simply try with `spinner.setSelection(0)`

It will be selected in top of spinner items.

Comment: ```spinner.setSelection(0)``` does not solve the problem cause it overwrites my hint which is not visible after selecting 0. I removed it and it does not solve the problem. It selects the item at 0 position. But I don't want to select I want to have unselected item